# How to minimize javascript files using grunt in mvvm framework using knockout js?

Tags: javascript

I am working on mvvm framework using knockout js .Using require js for AMD . I don't want to remove require js configuration.Could anyone help to minimize javascript files using grunt js along with require js ?

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
 requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                out: 'js/app.js',
                optimize: 'none',
                baseUrl: 'static/js',
                uglify2: {
                    output: {
                        'beautify': false
                    }
                },
                paths: {},// same as mentioned in build file of require js ,
                skipModuleInsertion: true,
                inlineText: true,
                name: 'app'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With grant you can use the plugins `grunt-contrib-concat` and `grunt-contrib-uglify`. Simply add the dependencies in your `package.json` and run `npm install` again.

Below you can find an simple example for a grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.initConfig({
                    concat: {
                        requirejs: {
                            src:['vendor/knockout/knockout.js', 'vendor/jquery/jquery.js'],
                            dest: 'dist/js/app.js'
                        }
                    },
                    uglify: {
                        requirejs: {
                            src:  'dist/js/app.js',
                            dest: 'dist/js/app.js'
                        }
                    },
                }
            );

            grunt.registerTask('build-requirejs', ['concat:requirejs', 'uglify:requirejs']);        
}
```

At the first step the task `build-requirejs` will concatenate the both js files `knockout.js` and `jquery.js` and stores the result in file `app.js`. The following step will uglify/minify the file `app.js`.

[Here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) you can find an overview about the uglify options